# Inverse of $f(x)=x+\text{log}(x)$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, inverse, curves

I have a problem, where the literature says that the following relationship is given:

$$M(z)=a_0z+a_1\text{log}(z)+a_2$$

This is completely fine. When I collect some $(z,M(z))$ pairs, I can do some curve fitting to find the coefficients. The problem that I have is the fact that everyone who graphs the results puts $M(z)$ in the $x$ axis and $z$ in the $y$ axis like shown here:

[image]

I know I can just flip the axis to draw the relationship like in Fig. 6.1 , but I want to know what is $z$ in terms of $M(z)$. When I want to invert $M(z)$ in Wolfram, it tells me "No results found in terms of standard mathematical functions"

Hence my question is can I invert this function to put $z$ in terms of $M(z)$?

The graph I get:

[image]

Comment: Never heard of it, will have a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik, thanks i got it now, If you want to, put this as an answer instead of comment and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$y(z)=a_0z+a_1\ln(z)+a_2$$
$$\frac{y-a_2}{a_1}=\frac{a_0}{a_1}z+\ln(z)$$
$$e^{\frac{y-a_2}{a_1}}=z\:e^{\frac{a_0}{a_1}z}$$
$$\frac{a_0}{a_1}e^{\frac{y-a_2}{a_1}}=\frac{a_0}{a_1}z\:e^{\frac{a_0}{a_1}z}$$

Let :$\quad\begin{cases}
X=\frac{a_0}{a_1}z\\
Y=\frac{a_0}{a_1}e^{\frac{y-a_2}{a_1}}
\end{cases}$
$$Y=Xe^X$$
The inverse function of $Y(X)$ is 
$$X=W(Y)$$
$W$ is the Lambert W function. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html
$$\frac{a_0}{a_1}z=W\left(\frac{a_0}{a_1}e^{\frac{y-a_2}{a_1}}\right)$$
$$\boxed{z=\frac{a_1}{a_0}W\left(\frac{a_0}{a_1}e^{\frac{y-a_2}{a_1}}\right)}$$

EXAMPLE :  $\quad y=326.3+0.1701x-10.05\ln(x)$

[image]

Comment: It works when all coefficients are positive, it produces complex values when $a_1$ is negative. Do you know why?

Comment: Thisis probably not due to $a_1$ alone. The important is the value of $Y=\frac{a_0}{a_1}e^{\frac{y-a_2}{a_1}}$ . If $Y<e^{-1}$ then  $z$ will be complex. If $e^{-1}<Y<0$ they are two distinct solutions for $z$. If $Y>0$ the solution is unique. This is consistent with the shape of the curve pubilsed in your question: No point for small "modified refractory". Two points in a range. One point for larger values.

Comment: Yeah I understood that, but still I cannot find a way to produce a function that looks anything like the one in Figure 6.1 above. I have $y=326.3+0.1701x-10.05\text{log}x$, when I invert it only in region where it is real it still wrong. There must be something else I am missing. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't know what is your difficulty. See the curve at the end of my answer. Also take care of the base of logarithm. In my answer it's the Neperian logarithm. Isn't it logarithm base 10 in the published paper ?

Comment: It is indeed natural logarithm. I work in matlab. whenever I plot the function and I use "lambertw" function. It just goes to 0 straight away. Would you be able to add the code you used to create your answer?

Comment: My function is basically $x=-59.08*W(-0.0169*exp(32.4677-\frac{y}{10.05}))$. Plotting this function using "lambertw(x)" in matlab does not produce the graph you produced.

Comment: What do you mean? I am just plugging them into the formula you provided. $a_0=0.1701$, $a_1=-10.05$, hence $a_1/a_0=-59.08$ etc. I am really sorry if I am doing something extremely dumb, I have never seen the $W$ before.

Comment: OK. In fact I don't use mathlab. The program I use is written with Delphi (from Borland). After drawing the curve I close the program. The code is erased by the closure. So, I cannot check what was exactly the code when the curve was drawn. But we can check more directly. For example with $a_0=0.1701$ , $a_1=-10.05$ , $a_2=326.3$ and $y=300$ one should get $x=18.835$ Is it that you get with mathlab ? By the way, I delate my previous comments to avoid confusion of parameters.

Comment: Yes I do get it, the graphs look the same initially, but my graph just goes straight to 0 instead of turning around. I think it has something to do with the fact that matlab only draws one solution instead of two. I have added my graph to my question.

Comment: OK. I don't know how the Lambert W function is implemented in matlab. If it draw only one solution instead of two in the range $-1/e<Y<0$ this means that only the branch $W_0(Y)$ is computed. Look at the doccumentation for the branch $W_{-1}$. On my graph the lowest part of the curve corresponds to $W_0(Y)$ and the  highest part of the curve corresponds to $W_{-1}(Y)$.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! It works, but I need to plot 2 functions, one for W(0,x) and one for W(-1,x). I just need to figure out how to make Matlab draw it automatically. Thanks again for the patience with me.

Comment: If the aim is not for numerical calculus, but if you only want to draw the curve, there is no need for the explicit equation of the inverse function (no need for the Lambert W function). That is much simpler. Just implement the function $y(x)=a_0x+a_1\ln(x)+a_2$ and plot$(y,x)$ instead of $(x,y)$. Or if you prefer plot the symetrical of $(x,y)$ relatively to the diagonal $y=x$. .